# You tube videos of a particular personality

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I want to add videos of my favourite personality in my website. So basically i want to do two tasks:

1. Get videos from youtube of that personality using You tube API or something.

For this I tried the following

```
$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?
     q=personalityname
     &start-index=0
     &max-results=10
     &v=2";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($body);
```

but i didn't got my results. 
Can any one help with my first task

Comment: Why don't you just embed the videos in your site?

Comment: But for that i would have to keep updating them regularly. And i would manually have to add new videos

Answer (score 0):

Use V3, would be much easier 'GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2C+snippet&q=personalityname&key={YOUR_API_KEY}'

"https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list"